# Autofac C#. Как при регистрации зависимостей создавать для них scope?

Tags: c#, .net, di, autofac

не могу разобраться с документацией Autofac, на предмет ручного задания scope на зависимость.

```
//КОНСТРУКТОРЫ ФОРМ
    ctor ScopeForm_1(Func<ScopeChildForm_1> childForm1Factory, Owned<ILogger> logger);
    ctor ScopeChildForm_1(ILogger logger);

    ctor ScopeForm_2(Func<ScopeChildForm_2> childForm2Factory, Owned<ILogger> logger);
    ctor ScopeChildForm_2(ILogger logger);
//РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ
builder.RegisterType<NyLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ScopeForm_1>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<ScopeForm_2>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<ScopeChildForm_1>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<ScopeChildForm_2>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Если производить регистрацию в глобальном scope, то ScopeChildForm_1 и ScopeChildForm_2 получит один и тоже logger, для ScopeForm_1 - свой экземпляр logger, для ScopeForm_2 - свой экземпляр logger.

Я так понимаю когда я регистрирую все сервисы я регистрирую их в глобальном scope(и задаю время жизни относительно этого scope)

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterType<NyLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerDependency(); 
 builder.RegisterType<NyLogger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

InstancePerDependency - каждый раз создается новый  объект.
 InstancePerLifetimeScope - один и тот же объект на всю программу, как Singleton, т.к. весь резолв будет происходить из одного скоупа (ГЛОБАЛЬНОГО),
 за исключением обертки Owned, в ней тоже происходит создание нового объекта с ручным контролем времени жизни.

> МНЕ НУЖНО ЧТОБЫ: Для ScopeForm_1 и для ScopeChildForm_1 создается один
>   logger в своем scope. Также ScopeForm_1 управляет временем жизни этого
>   logger, через Owned. Для ScopeForm_2 аналогичная пара только в другом
>   scope

Comment: Я так понимаю используя IOwner я создаю scope обертку и вызывая  Dispose() я пытаюсь уничтожить сервис и все его зависимости, если зависимости не Singleton они будут уничтожены. В примере выше если я закрываю ScopeForm_1 я хочу уничтожить ILogger, при открытии формы я хочу создать ILogger, при открытии дочереней формы  ScopeChildForm_1, я хочу передать уже созданный в ScopeForm_1  ILogger.

Comment: Ой не заметил даже "Owned" конечно, исвиняюсь

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема - вы не можете управлять временем жизни `ILogger` и зависящими от него `ScopeChildForm_1` независимо! Что будет если вы освободите ILogger пока какие-то `ScopeChildForm_1` еще существуют? Поэтому первое что нужно сделать - подготовить общий контейнер для `ILogger` и фабрики всех дочерних форм:

```
public class WithLogger<T>
{
    private Func<T> Factory { get; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; }

    public WithLogger(Func<T> factory, ILogger logger)
    {
        Factory = factory;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public T Create() => Factory();
}
```

Ну а дальше все просто:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(WithLogger<>)).ExternallyOwned();
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(new TypedService(typeof(WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_1>)), new TypedService(typeof(WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_2>)));

// ...

public ScopeForm_1(Owned<WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_1>> childForm1Factory);
public ScopeForm_2(Owned<WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_2>> childForm2Factory);
```

Отмечу, что если бы форма была всего одна, то можно было бы сделать чуть проще:

```
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerOwned<WithLogger<ScopeChildForm>>();
```

---

Если же кажется что в этом всем слишком много магии - можно сделать вот так. Для начала, изменим контейнер чтобы избавиться от Owned:

```
public interface ILifetimeScopeOwner : IDisposable
{
    event Action Disposed;
}

public class WithLogger<T> : ILifetimeScopeOwner
{
    private Func<T> Factory { get; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; }
    public event Action Disposed;

    public WithLogger(Func<T> factory, ILogger logger)
    {
        Factory = factory;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public T Create() => Factory();

    public void Dispose() => Disposed?.Invoke();
}
```

Дальше понадобится способ создавать такие контейнеры в отдельных скоупах. Для этого придется завести отдельный источник регистраций. Описание работы этого всего тянет на небольшую статью, поэтому просто привожу код с комментариями:

```
/// <summary>
/// Источник регистраций для обобщенных контейнеров, позволяющий им работать как Owned (т.е. создавать свой вложенный scope и управлять им)
/// Источник вдохвовения: исходники класса Autofac.Features.OwnedInstances.OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource
/// </summary>
class OwnedContainerSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    private readonly Type definition;
    private readonly object tag;

    public OwnedContainerSource(Type definition, object tag)
    {
        this.definition = definition;
        this.tag = tag;

        if (!typeof(ILifetimeScopeOwner).IsAssignableFrom(definition))
            throw new ArgumentException("must be assignable to ILifetimeScopeOwner", "definition");
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => true;

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        TypedService ts = service as TypedService;
        if (ts == null || ts.ServiceType != definition && (!ts.ServiceType.IsGenericType || ts.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != definition))
            yield break;

        // Ищем "внутреннюю" регистрацию. Это делается для того чтобы не создавать объект вручную.
        var innerRegistration = registrationAccessor(new KeyedService("inner", ts.ServiceType)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (innerRegistration == null || innerRegistration.Ownership != InstanceOwnership.ExternallyOwned)
            throw new NotSupportedException("inner registration must exist and be ExternallyOwned");

        // Все ок, можно создавать запрошенную регистрацию
        yield return RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(ts.ServiceType, (ctx, @params) =>
        {
            // Создаем вложенный скоуп, а в нем - резолвим объект
            var scope = ctx.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>().BeginLifetimeScope(tag);
            var container = (ILifetimeScopeOwner)scope.ResolveComponent(innerRegistration, @params);
            container.Disposed += scope.Dispose;
            return container;
        }).Targeting(innerRegistration).ExternallyOwned().CreateRegistration();
    }
}
```

Ну а дальше - снова все довольно просто:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new OwnedContainerSource(typeof(WithLogger<>), "form")); // Источник для "внешних" регистраций, создает отдельный скоуп с именем form на каждый запрос
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(WithLogger<>)).Named("inner", typeof(WithLogger<>)).ExternallyOwned(); // Внутренняя регистрация, выполняется уже в новом скоупе
builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("form");

public ScopeForm_1(WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_1> childForm1Factory);
public ScopeForm_2(WithLogger<ScopeChildForm_2> childForm2Factory);
```

Обращаю внимание на строковые константы "inner" и "form". Первая используется для того чтобы найти "внутреннюю" регистрацию, вторая - как маркер для lifetime scope. В них нет ничего магического, можно использовать любые другие строки или даже объекты.

---

Еще одно направление куда можно копать - своя реализация интерфейса IComponentLifetime. Но это неканоничное направление, я не видел чтобы так кто-то делал.

Comment: Спасибо. Потренируюсь. Подскажите ScopeForm_1 и ScopeChildForm_1 теперь зависит от WithLogger<ILogger >? или фабрика вызывается автоматом а зависимости простые от ILogger.

Comment: Конечно же они зависят от ILogger а не от фабрики!