# Использование ILifetimeScope как зависимости

Tags: c#, autofac

Считается что резолв зависимостей не в корне компановки это плохая архитектура (ServiceLocator).
Но у меня возникла задача по созданию объектов в цикле внутри сервиса.

Нужно создавать ITrainRecBuilder внутри цикла foreach.
Нормально ли это?

```
foreach (var uit in inputDatas)
{
    using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())         
    {
       var trainRecBuilder = scope.Resolve<ITrainRecBuilder>();
    }
}
```

GetCisRegSh - SingleInstance

IUsersRepository - SingleInstance

TrainRecService - InstancePerDependency

```
public class GetCisRegSh : GetSheduleAbstract
{
    private readonly IUsersRepository _usersRepository;
    private readonly TrainRecService _trainRecService;
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public GetCisRegSh(IUsersRepository usersRepository,
                       TrainRecService trainRecService,
                       ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) 
    {
        _usersRepository = usersRepository;
        _trainRecService = trainRecService;
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    protected override async Task GetaDataRxEventHandler(Task<IEnumerable<UniversalInputType>> getDataTask)
    {
        try
        {
            //ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ДАННЫХ--------------------------------------------------------
            var data = await getDataTask;
            var inputDatas = data as IList<UniversalInputType> ?? data.ToList();

            //СОЗДАНИЕ РАСПИСАНИЯ НА БАЗЕ ПОЛУЧЕННЫХ ДАННЫХ---------------------------
            var resultList = new List<TrainTableRec>();
            foreach (var uit in inputDatas)
            {
                using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())               //РЕЗОЛВ ITrainRecBuilder
                {
                    var trainRecBuilder = scope.Resolve<ITrainRecBuilder>();
                    var trainRec = trainRecBuilder
                        .SetExternalData(uit)
                        .SetDirectionByName(uit.Direction.Name)
                        .SetStationsById(uit.StationArrival.Id, uit.StationDeparture.Id)
                        .SetAllByTypeId(uit.TrainTypeByRyle.Id)
                        .Build();

                    resultList.Add(trainRec);
                }
            }

            //ПЕРЕЗАПИСАТЬ РЕПОЗИТОРИЙ RemoteCis
            _trainRecService.ReWriteAll(resultList, TrainRecRepType.RemoteCis);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не нормально. Запрашивайте лучше `Func<ITrainRecBuilder>`. Или даже `Func<Owned<ITrainRecBuilder>>` если есть хоть какой-то шанс что реализация `ITrainRecBuilder` будет владеть какими-нибудь ресурсами.

```
private readonly Func<Owned<ITrainRecBuilder>> builderFactory;

// ...

using (var scope = builderFactory()) 
{
    var builder = scope.Value;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Опять помогли. Переделал программу WinForms с использованием DI Autofac, стало гораздо проще поддерживать код. У меня остался 1 вопрос с которым я не разобрался, хотелось бы иметь контроль над скоупами при регистрации.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804882/autofac-c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-scope?rq=1